# Is sending recaptchaPublicKey & RecaptchaToken in the post request a potential security threat?

Tags: asp.net, security, https, recaptcha

I have implemented reCaptcha in login form to slow down the potential brute force attack. However, the application sends recaptchaPublicKey & RecaptchaToken in the post request along with the login credentials. Does it lead to a security threat? As per my understanding, if the application reflects secrets ( such as tokens) in HTTP response bodies, that will be classified as potential BREACH (Browser Reconnaissance & Exfiltration via Adaptive Compression of Hypertext) attack.

Is it safe to send RecaptchaToken in post request?

Answer (score 0):

Where/How do you want to send them then?

You'll have to send the **User Response Token** that came from the reCaptcha Control through **POST** to your endpoint. You also need to make sure that the data are sent through **SSL/TLS**.